# What is java CompletableFuture equivalent of scala Future rescue and handle

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I see that `CompletableFuture` has a method `handle` that is the same as that of scala `Future`'s `handle` basically converting success and exceptions all to success to be `map` and `flatMap` upstream(or `thenApply` and `thenCompose` in java world).

What is the equivalent of twitter future `rescue`(or scala future `recoverWith`) in java though?

`rescue` in scala is basically like the old java `try....catch`, then rethrow with more information so it can be nice to use.  For example in `twitterFuture.handle` or `scalaFuture.recover` the return unit is `U` so you return a response.  In `twitterFuture.rescue` or `scalaFuture.recoverWith`, it returns `Future[U]` so one can take certain exceptions, add more info and return `Future.exception(xxxxx)`

Comment: I don't see anything called `rescue` in Scala's API doc, do you mean [`recover`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recover[U%3E:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U]) (though this is more like `try/catch` than `try/finally`)?

Comment: @kennytm http://twitter.github.io/util/docs/#com.twitter.util.Future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `recover`, if you don't need to return a superclass and want to swallow all exceptions, you could just use [`exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-):

```
CompletableFuture<T> future = ...;
CompletableFuture<T> newFuture = future.exceptionally(_exc -> defaultValue);
```

Otherwise, you need to use [`handle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to get a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<U>>`, and then use [`thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) to collapse it:

```
CompletableFuture<T> future = ...;
CompletableFuture<T> newFuture = future.handle((v, e) -> {
        if (e == null) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(v);
        } else {
            // the real recoverWith part
            return applyFutureOnTheException(e);
        }
    }).thenCompose(Function.identity());
```

Comment: thinking out loud here.  But what if the v in the response is null.  Does it need to be reversed to if(e != null) return applyFutureOnException() as I thought v can be null but e can never be null or do I have this wrong..

Comment: @DeanHiller Swapped the branches.