# java completable futures and exception chaining

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I have the following code

```
    return future.exceptionally(t -> {
        if(t instanceof NotFoundException)
            return processNotFound(responseCb, requestCtx, (NotFoundException) t, errorRoutes, null);

        throw new CompletionException(t.getMessage(), t);
        //in scala we would return new CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(t) and not throw
    });
```

where processNotFound returns a CompletableFuture as well that could have failed.

Basically, these steps
1. hit primary system
2. catch exception for recovery
3. return future of recovery that may have failed or succeeded

I know how to do this in scala but am not sure how to do this in java.  anyone know?

Comment: Why not just use [scala to java solution](http://javatoscala.com/)

Comment: no thanks, too big a progam to convert @user7790438

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: @user7790438 That tool works the other way around anyway: java to scala.

Comment: Isn't it the same question as [What is java CompletableFuture equivalent of scala Future rescue and handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940494/what-is-java-completablefuture-equivalent-of-scala-future-rescue-and-handle)? Anyway if your code works I don't think there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @DidierL close but slightly different though maybe that solution works for this.  I will have to try that out.  In the previous post I only wanted to chain exceptions.  here I want to try to recover and return the result of trying to recover.  In the previous post I have no intention of recovering at all.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I came up with my own solution which is a hack

```
public static <T> ExceptionOrResult<T> convert(Throwable t, T res) {
    return new ExceptionOrResult<T>(t, res);
}

/**
 * This sucks as I could not find a way to compose failures in java(in scala they have a function for this)
 */
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> composeFailure(CompletableFuture<T> future, Function<Throwable, CompletableFuture<T>> exceptionally) {
    return future.handle((r, t) -> convert(t, r)).thenCompose((r) -> {
        if(r.getException() == null)
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(r.getResult());
        return exceptionally.apply(r.getException());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Java 8 doesn't have Maybe inbuilt, but it should be pretty simple to add(similar to your answer above). Here's a library that does it: https://github.com/npryce/maybe-java

But if you just want to return a CompletableFuture, you can try using `.thenCompose()` method. Here's an example:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> getCompletableFuture(CompletableFuture<Integer> future) {
    return future.handle((r, ex) -> {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> res = new CompletableFuture<>();
        if (ex != null) {
            res.complete(r);
        } else {
            res.completeExceptionally(ex);
        }
        return res;
    }).thenCompose(cf -> cf);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, not that I love Java but it *does* have `Maybe`, its just called `Optional`